# Mocking datetime.now(); mock object isn't recognized as a class

Tags: python

I'm trying to mock the output of datetime.now() to simulate the passage of time. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from mock import Mock, patch
from other_module import some_code

tomorrow = Mock(spec=datetime)
tomorrow.now = Mock(return_value=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
with patch('other_module.datetime', tomorrow):
    some_code()
```

This would work fine, except `some_code()` is using a library, [croniter](https://github.com/kiorky/croniter), that specifically takes the `datetime.datetime` class as input and checks that it is a subclass of `datetime.datetime`. This is the problem I'm running into; while datetime.datetime is a class, my mock is not; it's not recognized as a class type by the `issubclass` method.

How can I make sure that my mock object is recognized as a class?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are structuring your unittests, but technically you should be mocking out whatever class/method you are calling from croniter so it does not effect your unittest. Your goal is to test the behaviour of calling `some_code()`.

Comment: I guess that's a possible solution, but this is part of an integration test, not a unit test, so I'm trying to mock as few things as possible

Comment: Mocking in an integration test seems very strange. Are you trying to manipulate times to help with your integration test to force some time constraint?

Comment: If that is what you are trying to do, maybe something like [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) might help?

Comment: I'm testing a scheduling system. The system will allow users to set the schedule of certain events, e.g. "every Monday, Wednesday, Friday, send me a weekly email about yada yada". This is verifying that the logic of the scheduling system is sound. The system relies on the output of datetime.now(), so I thought this makes sense.

Comment: You should look at freezegun. Someone even posted an answer about it just now.

Comment: Awesome thanks @idjaw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with croniter, but [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) may help with this— it patches all references to `datetime.datetime` with instances of `freezegun.api.FakeDatetime`, so within `some_code()`, any `datetime.datetimes` should use instances of `freezegun.api.FakeDatetime`. Speaking from experience, you'll also save yourself lots of headaches with intermittent test failures when trying to simulate the passage of time if you use freezegun.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from freeze_gun import freeze_time
from other_module import some_code

fake_today = datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 11)
with_freeze_time(fake_today):
    some_code()
# simulate passage of time to tomorrow
with_freeze_time(fake_today + timedelta(days=1))
    some_code()
```